# Get string of specific part of href value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, href

In the HTML source code of a page, we have:

```
<li class="wv-topbar__nav__item">
  <a href="/go/business_savings/933dd921-b3d4-be4d-bb0d-e45fe696643d/" class="wv-topbar__nav__link">
    Save Money
  </a>
</li>
```

I want to be able to get this string from the href value:

```
933dd921-b3d4-be4d-bb0d-e45fe696643d
```

Basically, the string between the 3rd and 4th slash and store it into a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Just one liner :

```
  alert($('.wv-topbar__nav__item a') // select anchor element inside the element with class = wv-topbar__nav__item
   .attr('href').split('/')[3]);
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/cfrjqvya/

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, it would look something like this

```
var urlKey = $(".wv-topbar__nav__item a").prop("href").split("/")[3]
```

To access the `href` attribute, we can use either the `attr` or `prop` functions. This returns us a string.

To find the part after a delimiter, we can call the `split` method and take the fourth result.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = $('.wv-topbar__nav__link').attr('href').split('/')[3];
```

Comment: that won't work since li doesn't have href attribute

Comment: yep add the descendant selector after your selector and it will work

Comment: I am using the class of the anchor, not the li. This would be true for ".wv-topbar__nav__item"

Comment: no worries! I would argue this is better than adding the anchor selector after the li's class since it may break in the future if more anchors are added to the li